# Got a weird error with cx_Freeze compiled Python & Pygame Document as a .exe file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm creating a video game with Python 2.7 and Pygame 1.9. I compiled it with cx_Freeze 4.3.4. When I run the .exe file, I get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've looked around the web and around this site but haven't found anything that can really help me. I'm using the default pygame font. So fonts cant be it.

If this helps, I made it  in 32 bit format. You can find the source code below.

The Python Source Code can be found [here](https://github.com/OrionDark7/Deeper/blob/master/Deeper.py).

All of the Assets can be found [here](https://github.com/OrionDark7/Deeper/tree/master).

Thanks for your time, OrionDark7.

Comment: The segmentation fault error does not really give much insight into solving the issue with cx_Freeze. Could you post exactly what steps you are taking to compile your game?

Comment: Well, to start, I make the setup.py file, and add the setup scripts. Then, I open a command window at the parent folder and type `C:\Python27\python setup.py bdist_msi`. It compiles that succesfuly, and I complete the download proccess for the .msi installer file. Then, I go to the Folder where the assests installed and run the .exe file it created. I then get that error.

Comment: Can you post the contents of setup.py here? I could not find it on the github page you linked to in the question. There is a good chance that the issue is there.

Comment: Sure! You can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/MfuHKva0). Could it be the .dat file or .txt file thats causing the problem?

Comment: Never mind, figured out it was indeed the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out, indeed, it was the font. Instead of:

```
pygame.font.Font(None, 1)
```

It should be:

```
pygame.font.Font("Font Filepath and Filename here", 1)
```

Sorry if I wasted your time. Was just trying to figure it out.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: I will. I have to wait 11 more hours though.